# Rails: is there an Engine.root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

`Rails.root` returns a Path object specifying the root of a Rails project.

Is there an equivilent for Rails engines? Like `Engine.root`? If not, how else could I build up a path from the root of my Rails engine?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Lets say your engine file is set up like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    #......
  end
end
```

You can call root on the Engine class like this:

```
MyEngine::Engine.root
```

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is right, but I'd clean that up a little bit like this:

When you mount your engine within your routes file add an alias first.

```
mount YourEngineNameHere::Engine => '/optional_namespace', as: 'your_engine_name'
```

Then do your_engine_name.root_url

Comment: This answer is confused about the question which is about file paths, not urls and routing. i.e Instead of doing `Rails.root.join('some', 'file.csv')` how would you get a file from the file system in an engine relative to the filesystem path where the engine is mounted.