# Convert a partial to method/block for speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, partial

I have a loop that renders a partial

```
1000.times do |i|
  render partial: 'test', locals: {i: i}
end
```

this is really slow, up to 0.1 ms for foreach render call, even if the partial only prints out `i`

```
my_partial = render_to_method(partial: 'test')
1000.times do |i|
  my_partial(locals: {i: i})
end
```

Now this should be doing the same thing way faster right? But I don't know how to do this.

**update:**

I've tried the to do it this way:

```
Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.expand_path File.dirname(FILE)+"/../table/#{column.macro}/_#{column.display_type}.haml"))
.‌​render(OpenStruct.new({column_value: column_value, object: object}))
```

two major drawbacks:

- The path to the views will not watch for fallbacks like it does when you do it with render (parital: 'partial' will look for the parital in the current view dir, in some gems and also in the view/application.
- The Rails view helpers aren't available any more

**update 2:**

Many of the answers try to solve the problem by using other techniques. I my real application this techniques can't be applied. https://github.com/antpaw/bhf/blob/master/app/views/bhf/pages/_platform.haml#L54‌​ mainly because this line is a dynamic string that sometimes links to partials that don't even exsist in the gem and are defined in the main_app. I wonder why it's so hard to do something that is so basic: 1. grab the view. 2. render it. (3. render it again.)

**update 3:**

@Flash Gordon suggested this https://gist.github.com/antpaw/d6670c23d6f08e35812e#file-gistfile1-haml-L54

```
template = lookup_context.find_template "#{column.macro}/#{column.display_type}", ['bhf/table'], true
template.render(self, {column_value: column_value, object: object})
```

it almost works just having some troubles with `locals`. But it already feels like the part where you grab the template and the render part is well separated.

Comment: Try precompile template before rendering.

Comment: @Vakiliy can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: For example, like this https://github.com/vakiliy/templates_benchmark/blob/master/benchmark.rb#L83

Comment: Why not just bring the iterator within the partial? If the iterator (i) is variable, you can pass it with the locals hash.

Comment: @RubyRacer this is a very simple example, in real world it wouldn't work that easy

Comment: @Vakiliy thanks it works, two problems i have right now are: I need to know what kind of template i have (haml/erb/...) `partial:` doesn't need that. And i don't know how to build a path to the partials because they are saved in a engine gem (`File.read(Dir.pwd+"/../bhf/app/views/bhf/table/#{column.macro}/_#{column.display_type}.haml")`) this won't work in production i guess :)

Comment: @antpaw, did not understand question, path you engine http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125165/3681493 , you may use predefined paths: YouEngine::Engine.paths['app/views']

Comment: @Vakiliy yea sorry the second question was a bit off, but the first one is really important, and by precompiling the template it loses the option to use rails helpers like `sanitize`

Comment: Of course not, @antpaw, but the general idea is the same. For example, I have been using the awesome_nested_sets, where in documentation shows how to build a tree with nested partials.. I've done it using a recursive function instead. I mean, use plain programming instead of consecutive partial calls is the main idea. At least, in my point of view.

Comment: Rails already does create a method from the partial. The template code is compiled into Ruby source which is wrapped with `def <method_name>`  and is `eval`ed and a dynamically named method is created. Your attempt using `Haml::Engine` directly would likely be slower, since `render` there will re-`eval` the compiled Ruby code on each call.

Comment: @matt can you give an example (as an answer)?

Comment: I don’t really know how I could provide an example, the best I can do is probably point you at the source for [`ActionView::Template`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.4/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb) where most of this happens, in particular the [`compile` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.4/actionview/lib/action_view/template.rb#L267-L308).

Comment: If the answers you're getting here won't work because they only solve the problem for a simple case, perhaps you need to expand on your example so that everyone better understands the complexity of your problem. @bbozo has a good point: maybe you really have a design problem and should reconsider your approach.

Comment: @SteveMadsen But it's really not about my case at all. Just the question headline, it's a simple feature that every other templating system has, and I want to find out how to use it.

Comment: @antpaw, if that's the case then I fear the question isn't clear since its phrased as a performance problem. Also, you seem to be kind of reinventing the wheel by trying to call `render partial` without calling `render partial` :) Have you tried creating a helper method that returns the result of a "render" call? :) Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @antpaw If you don't have a concrete problem you're trying to solve, then you're unlikely to get useful answers and this question will mostly attract subjective opinions, i.e., be eligible for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from one of my previous answers. It's extracted from `PartialRenderer` sources.

```
- local_names = [:i]
- partials = {}
- 1000.times do |i|
  - name = 'name_%s' % (i % 10)
  - partials[name] ||= lookup_context.find_template(name, lookup_context.prefixes, true, local_names)
  = partials[name].render(self, i: i)
```

I'd recommend you to wrap it with a helper method. Keep in mind that locals' names appear here *twice*: first in `local_names` as an array and second in hash's keys passed as the second argument of `#render` method.

Answer (score 5):

I love this question, but it may be a "wrong tool for the job" thing

Basically:

1. if the partial is simple - consider not using a partial at all, the overhead isn't worth it
2. if the partial is complex - then rendering 1000s of things will take TIME out of which partial overhead is just a fraction of, you'll need a plan B

Plan Bs:

1. render 25-50-100.... thingies at first and fetch additional records from the server as the user scrolls - http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page
2. send a JSON array from the server and let client side JS iterate through the collection and render HTML - this way the partial template can still be rendered in rails and client side JS can do `gsub`
3. cache everything you possibly can - this doesn't include forms unfortunately which are typically the slowest rendering components
4. ...

PS have you tried out cells? https://github.com/apotonick/cells

Comment: I don't think it's a '"wrong tool for the job" thing'. Please read the "update 3" in my question.

Comment: A fair question :) in "update 3", are you sure you aren't reinventing the exact same thing that `render` does?

Comment: for now yes, but when this simple case works 100% i will make it more complicated and take out the definition of the template out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting proposition and it seems harder than I thought to find information about it. However from what I can tell from the implementation of the [`response` object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ffadb52704b2c3e123a0305de357a156ccee192/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb#L174) I would think it should be possible to append (`<<`) your output to the `stream` object of the `response` object. This will be rendered as a string into the `response#body` as necessary.

The tricky part is to find a good place to define your `my_partial` method. While it is not commonplace to do this in a `View` it should still be possible and I *think* you should have access to the `response` object directly. Otherwise you might define it in a helper, though you probably do not want to use this code in a controller.

Sorry if this is rather an idea than an answer, but I lack the time to test it properly.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to explain

Comment: @antpaw I had the impression (probably wrong) that you wanted to write a regular ruby message to use instead of the partial in order to speed it up. So I tried to figure out how this would have to be done as I have not seen it very often (outside of `Erector` and lately [`Fortidue`](https://github.com/ageweke/fortitude) that is).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper method and use `content_tag`. This accomplishes your goal of having a method work as a partial.

```
def my_partial(i)
  content_tag(:div, i, class: 'iterator')
end
```

Using helper methods with `content_tag` probably isn't a good solution if you have a lot of content in your partial, for readability's sake.

**An alternative recommendation:** Instead of rendering the same partial multiple times within a loop, you could render a single partial that includes a loop. If you needed to reuse the partial for only one object, you could just pass the object as an array.

Here's a more real-world example:

```
# index.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'dogs', locals: {dogs: @dogs} %>

# show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'dogs', locals: {dogs: [@dog]} %>

# _dogs.html.erb
<% dogs.each do |dog| %>
  <%= dog.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the first drawback applies to the first solution. the secound solution doesn't work in a compilcated case like this: https://github.com/antpaw/bhf/blob/master/app/views/bhf/pages/_platform.haml#L54

Answer (score 0):

Use `:collection` option:

```
= render partial: 'test', collection: 10.times.to_a, as: :i
```

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb#L284

Comment: Yes this solves the problem described in the question, but doesn't answer the question. I can't use this because my partial links are dynamic https://github.com/antpaw/bhf/blob/master/app/views/bhf/pages/_platform.haml#L54, I'm sorry my question example was a bit too simple.

Comment: I did not found well known API but you could do so: `partials ||= {}; partials[name] ||= lookup_context.find_template(name, lookup_context.prefixes, true, [local_names_list]); partials[name].render(self, locals)`. `name` for partial name and `local_names_list` for list of locals' keys (`[:column_value, :object]` in your case) and `locals` for variables hash (i.e. `{column_value: column_value, object: object}`)

Comment: yes it does work! but I'm having problems with locals https://gist.github.com/antpaw/d6670c23d6f08e35812e#file-gistfile1-haml-L54 this breaks with this error `undefined local variable or method 'column_value' for #<#<Class:0x000001024e5450>:0x00000109b0fc98> ` but it feels like we are really close, please submit this as an answer so i can give you bounty points

Comment: you are missing list of locals' names in the end of call of `#find_template` method—`[:column_value, :object]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need render many times and it is slow, I suggest you do not call `render` many times. I know, I am captain obvious.

If `locals` contains simple strings or numbers, try to render your view once, and then just replace parts with actual variables.

```
text = render(partial: 'test', locals: {i: '$'})

1000.times do |i|
  output[i] = text.gsub('$', i)
end
```