# How to speed up rendering of a rails_partial with form elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rendering

I have `rails` action that includes the following `HAML` partial:

```
- @items.each_with_index do |item, i|
  - item_no = 'item' + item.item_no.to_s
  .item
    = form_for item, remote: true, html: { multipart: true, autocomplete: 'off' } do |f|
      = f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => @parent.id
      = f.hidden_field :image, value: item.image
      ...
      ...
      // 5-6 attributes

    - if @parent.has_item_numbers?
      .serial-number{ class: ('right' if item.item_no.odd?)  }
        = item.item_no
```

Number of `items` associated with its `parent` can vary greatly and can go up to 2000-3000 as well depending on user. We don't have limit on the number of children the parent can have yet. Before I can decide a `limit:`, is there a way to speedup rendering off `.each_with_index` method because right now this is taking up to 10 seconds to complete a request on my local.

There is some discussion of [converting a partial to a method/block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238518/convert-a-partial-to-method-block-for-speed) for speed but I don't understand it fully.

Also, of note is that this same partial was performing much better in `rails 5.0.4` but it has slowed down considerably with `rails 5.1.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally not iterate in your views. Instead, you should use [collection rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#rendering-collections) which will perform the iteration for you, and is [known to be faster](https://dev.firmafon.dk/blog/rails-5-much-faster-collection-rendering/) in addition to allowing you to implement fragment caching:

Your view:

```
= render @items, parent: @parent
```

Your partial (ie `_item.html.haml`):

```
- item_no = 'item' + item.item_no.to_s
.item
  = form_for item, remote: true, html: { multipart: true, autocomplete: 'off' } do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => @parent.id
    = f.hidden_field :image, value: item.image
    ...
    ...
    // 5-6 attributes

  - if parent.has_item_numbers?
    .serial-number{ class: ('right' if item.item_no.odd?)  }
      = item.item_no
```

Comment: This hangs the puma server completely on my local each time I open the view with a large collection. Still digging… brb.

Comment: Third last line on the answer should be `- if @parent.has_item_numbers?`. The times are now in the range of 2.5-3.5 seconds. Looking at fragment caching now: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @marvindanig I explicitly pass in `parent` in the `render` call, it's generally better for your partials to not reference instance variables like `@parent`. You should inject your dependencies explicitly.

Comment: @marvindanig Also note: You were originally doing `each_with_index`, but not doing anything with the index, so I left that out. If you *do* need the index within your partial, it should be available as `item_iteration` http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: How do you mean?  --> "You should inject your dependencies explicitly. " Yes, the index is saved in the `item_table` so I no longer need `each_with_index` method. Thank you setting me in the right direction @meagar

Comment: What I mean is, inside your partials you shouldn't generally depend on `@` variables being set. Partials are meant for code-reuse, and the next time you render that partial from some other view, there might not be a `@parent`, either because that view doesn't load that variable, or because it's named something different like `@parent_item` in that context, or for whatever other reason. `@` variables are best used in top-level views, which can then pass named local variables into partials.