# How to get mountable engine path in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a middleware inside a mountable engine, and I need to know the mount point of the engine. How would i do this in Rails 5? I've tried `MyEng::Engine.routes._generate_prefix({})` but that does not work in Rails 5.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Solution found. See [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352671/1498118).

Answer (score 3):

#### Update after [E L Rayle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2854941/e-l-rayle) comment

If you want to get the path on which the engine is mounted you can use the following method:

```
MyEng::Engine.routes.find_script_name({})
```

See comments for more details.

#### [previous wrong answer]

I think you are looking for this one: `MyEngine::Engine.root`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117729/rails-is-there-an-engine-root)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Unfortunately the answer is not correct for the question.  `MyEng::Engine.root` returns the file path to the gem code (e.g. `~/.rvm/gems/ruby2.4.3@my_gemset/bundler/gems/my_eng-e870ff07c991`).  The question is looking for the URL path defined in routes.rb. (e.g. `'my_eng'` as defined in `mount MyEng => '/my_eng'`).  `_generate_prefix` used to return this.

Comment: I see what you mean, so I've been looking for `_generate_prefix` and I've seen it has been replaced with `find_script_name`. You can see the [old use here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bb21d6ed7adc899435f32e297115fe98381e71d4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L628) and the [current use here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L812).

Comment: I haven't had the time to look further into it, but might be helpful if someone is willing to investigate a bit more. The `find_script_name` method is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L786-L788) and can be used this way `MyEng::Engine.routes. find_script_name(options)` where `options` should a hash like the one described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L118-L170).

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for figuring this out and updating your answer.  It worked like a charm.